# Plotting the equation for an ellipse, not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I obtained this equation for for an ellipse -> (0.375 * x^2) + (0.4375 * y^2) + (0.5 * y) - 3.732

I tried plotting it in Python:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

q = -np.linspace(5,10,100)
p = np.linspace(-25,29,1000)

p,q = np.meshgrid(p,q)
Q = (0.4375 * (q**2)) - (0.5 * q) - 3.732
P = (p**2) * 0.375

pline = plt.contour(p,q,(P+Q),[0]) 
plt.legend((pline), ('Curve'), loc='upper right', shadow=True)
```

I am getting a warning:

No contour levels were found within the data range.
Legend does not support  instances.

Is there a different way to plot the ellipse? How do I get around this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
`plt` is undefined in the code you posted.  `np` is also undefined, but I keep that handy in my working environment.

Comment: My apologies, I primarily wanted to know how I could plot that equation.

Comment: Start with leaving out plt.legend and the strange `[0]` in `plt.contour`.   Then, just try `plt.contour(p,q,(P+Q)); plt.show()`

Comment: I got different colored stripes instead of an ellipse @JohanC

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that the range of q and p weren't surrounding the ellipse. Choosing both between -5 and 5 seems to fit well. Choosing a colormap with a distinct color in the center helps to point out the place where the equation is zero. Setting vmin (the function value corresponding to the lowest color) and vmax (the function for the highest color) to be symmetrical to zero puts the center color at that zero.

`contour` doesn't generate a legend, but it does give indications in a colorbar.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

q = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
p = np.linspace(-5,5,200)

p,q = np.meshgrid(p,q)
Q = (0.4375 * (q**2)) - (0.5 * q) - 3.732
P = (p**2) * 0.375

plt.contour(p, q, (P+Q), levels=11, cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-5, vmax=5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The grey ellipse is the one where the equation is zero.
[image: example plot]

[Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), pythons symbolic math library, can make things easier by directly plotting an [implicit equation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html):

```
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit
from sympy.abc import p, q

Q = (0.4375 * (q**2)) - (0.5 * q) - 3.732
P = (p**2) * 0.375
plot_implicit(P+Q)
```

[image: sympy plot]

Comment: I am getting an error while using sympy :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assign2a.py", line 130, in <module>
    plot_implicit(P+Q)
  File "/home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot_implicit.py", line 326, in plot_implicit
    expr = Eq(expr, 0)
  File "/home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 474, in __new__
    lhs = _sympify(lhs)
  File "/home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 418, in _sympify
    return sympify(a, strict=True)

Comment: But it worked when I used the previous method you said @JohanC, so thanks. However I am scattering a set of points on the plane and when I plot this after, the earlier plots are overlapping this one.

Comment: I am not sure why my counter plot is hidden behind my other plots when the statement plt.contour is right before plt.show

Comment: You probably need to upgrade sympy, python and matplotlib to the latest versions. To put the new plot behind the points, you could do `plt.contour(...., zorder=0)`. The "z order" tells in which layer something has to be drawn; the higher the closer to the viewer).

Comment: Does this answer your original question?